# Adding Inventory Adjustment for QuickBooks using QuickBooks PHP Dev Kit/ QuickBooks Web Connector

Tags: php, sql, quickbooks

I'm having trouble getting a proper Inventory Adjustment to go through. It seems that it's not referencing/targeting a proper account within QuickBooks. And I'm not clear on where it's making it's connections and what to supply it with.

I'm still tinkering with it but any suggestions would be awesome.

**Update:** Changing AccountRef FullName to "Inventory Asset" gets rid of the errors and also updates RefNumber, TxnID, etc when it syncs. BUT, it's still not updating quantity in QuickBooks. Going to assume it's because it's only really passing "QuantityDifference".

**QWCLog.txt**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <?qbxml version="13.0"?>
        <QBXML>
            <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
                <InventoryAdjustmentAddRq requestID="13">
                    <InventoryAdjustmentAdd>



                        <AccountRef>
                            <FullName>Inventory Adjustments</FullName>
                        </AccountRef>

                        <TxnDate>2016-12-28</TxnDate>
                        <!--<RefNumber>9051</RefNumber>-->

                        <Memo></Memo>

                        <InventoryAdjustmentLineAdd>
                            <ItemRef>
                                <ListID>TxnLID-9051</ListID>
                            </ItemRef>

                            <QuantityAdjustment>
                                <QuantityDifference>0.00000</QuantityDifference>
                            </QuantityAdjustment>
                        </InventoryAdjustmentLineAdd>


                    </InventoryAdjustmentAdd>
                </InventoryAdjustmentAddRq>
            </QBXMLMsgsRq>
        </QBXML>

20161228.19:16:51 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_sendRequestXML() : Request xml received.
20161228.19:16:51 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.ProcessRequestXML() : Processing request #2
20161228.19:16:51 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.ProcessRequestXML() : REQUEST: received from application: size (bytes) = 1191
20161228.19:16:51 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.ProcessRequestXML() : Sending request to QuickBooks.
20161228.19:16:51 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.ProcessRequestXML() : Response received from QuickBooks: size (bytes) = 379
20161228.19:16:51 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.ProcessRequestXML() : Sending response back to application.
20161228.19:16:51 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_receiveResponseXML() : *** Calling receiveResponseXML() with following parameters:
20161228.19:16:51 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_receiveResponseXML() : wcTicket="3388bbdc-18d0-a594-7dfd-70f68aac289e"
20161228.19:16:51 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_receiveResponseXML() : response =
20161228.19:16:51 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_receiveResponseXML() : XML dump follows: -

<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<QBXML>
<QBXMLMsgsRs>
<InventoryAdjustmentAddRs requestID="13" statusCode="3140" statusSeverity="Error" statusMessage="There is an invalid reference to QuickBooks Account &quot;Inventory Adjustments&quot; in the InventoryAdjustment.  QuickBooks error message: Invalid argument.  The specified record does not exist in the list." />
</QBXMLMsgsRs>
</QBXML>
```

**save.php** Code that inserts and queues the Inventory Adjustment

```
$Queue = new QuickBooks_WebConnector_Queue($dsn);

// IMPORTANT: ONLY UPDATE CHANGED ROWS. WE DONT WANT INVENTORY ADJUSTMENTS FOR UNCHANGED ITEMS!
foreach ($updates as $update) {
    // Update QuantityOnHand still so our web interface can easily see the new quantity before QB sync
    $sql = "UPDATE qb_item SET QuantityOnHand='" . $update[1] . "' WHERE ListID='" . $update[0] . "'";
    if (!$qb_result = $qb->query($sql)) {
        dErr("Error: Our query failed to execute and here is why: <br />Query: " . $sql . "<br />Errno: " . $qb->errno . "<br />Error: " . $qb->error);
    }

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM qb_item WHERE ListID='" . $update[0] . "'";
    if (!$qb_result = $qb->query($sql)) {
        dErr("Error: Our query failed to execute and here is why: <br />Query: " . $sql . "<br />Errno: " . $qb->errno . "<br />Error: " . $qb->error);
    }

    $row = $qb_result->fetch_assoc();

    // Generate unique TxnID
    // Apparently QuickBooks will overwrite it with the permanent TxnID when it syncs
    $tID = rand(1000, 9999);

    // Insert new Item Adjustment
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `qb_inventoryadjustment` ( `TxnID`, `TimeCreated`, `TimeModified`,  `Account_FullName`, `TxnDate`, `RefNumber`,  `Memo`, `qbsql_discov_datetime`, `qbsql_resync_datetime`, `qbsql_modify_timestamp` ) VALUES ( 'TxnID-" . $tID . "', now(), now(),  'Inventory Adjustments', CURDATE(), '" . $tID . "', NULL, NULL, NULL, now() )";
    if (!$qb_result = $qb->query($sql)) {
        dErr("Error: Our query failed to execute and here is why: <br />Query: " . $sql . "<br />Errno: " . $qb->errno . "<br />Error: " . $qb->error);
    }

    // Get the primary key of the new record
    $id = $qb->insert_id;

    // Queue up the inventory adjustment
    $Queue->enqueue(QUICKBOOKS_ADD_INVENTORYADJUSTMENT, $id);

    // Insert new Item Adjustment Line
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `qb_inventoryadjustment_inventoryadjustmentline` ( `InventoryAdjustment_TxnID`, `SortOrder`, `TxnLineID`, `Item_ListID`, `Item_FullName`, `QuantityAdjustment_NewQuantity` ) VALUES ( 'TxnID-" . $tID . "', '0', 'TxnLID-" . $tID . "', '" . $update[0] . "', '" . $row['FullName'] . "', " . $update[1] . ")";
    if (!$qb_result = $qb->query($sql)) {
        dErr("Error: Our query failed to execute and here is why: <br />Query: " . $sql . "<br />Errno: " . $qb->errno . "<br />Error: " . $qb->error);
    }

    // Get the primary key of the new record
    $id = $qb->insert_id;

    // Queue up the inventory adjusment
    $Queue->enqueue(QUICKBOOKS_ADD_INVENTORYADJUSTMENT, $id);
}
```

Comment: I'll follow up since no seems to fully read anything anymore. If you take a look at my (old) save.php code you will notice I am not even passing "QuantityDifference" so all comments saying that I am passing the incorrect "QuantityDifference" are missing the point of my post. The issue was compounded for sure, and I must admit I did not fully grasp what was required (at that time). Not to mention Keith's docs are atrocious. The real answer to my question was (kind of) answered by Keith which led me to deduce which field held the proper Account for the Inventory Adjustment (Item Asset Account).

Answer (score 0):

Look in the QuickBooks UI/help or QuickBooks OSR.

The `QuantityDifference` field is defined as:

> QuantityDifference
>
> Either a positive or negative number that shows the
>   change in quantity for this inventory item.

You are sending:

```
<QuantityDifference>0.00000</QuantityDifference>
```

Which tells QuickBooks that you want to change the quantity by... `0`. You want to add `0` to the quantity, and subtract `0` from the quantity.

You should be able to tell which are the allowable accounts by looking in the QuickBooks UI.

Comment: As you can see in my OP, I have already came to that conclusion: `Going to assume it's because it's only really passing "QuantityDifference".` What I didn't understand was why you recommended for me to insert an InventoryAdjustment by ONLY updating "NewQuantity" (a key that does not even exist).

Answer (score 0):

Use this code for your xml request:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <?qbxml version="13.0"?>
    <QBXML>
        <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
            <InventoryAdjustmentAddRq requestID="13">
                <InventoryAdjustmentAdd>
                    <AccountRef>
                        <FullName>Inventory Asset</FullName>
                    </AccountRef>

                    <TxnDate>2016-12-28</TxnDate>
                    <!--<RefNumber>9051</RefNumber>-->
                    <Memo></Memo>

                    <InventoryAdjustmentLineAdd>
                        <ItemRef>
                            <ListID>TxnLID-9051</ListID>
                        </ItemRef>

                        <QuantityAdjustment>
                            <QuantityDifference>-3</QuantityDifference>
                        </QuantityAdjustment>
                    </InventoryAdjustmentLineAdd>


                </InventoryAdjustmentAdd>
            </InventoryAdjustmentAddRq>
        </QBXMLMsgsRq>
    </QBXML>
```

Your problem was with the account name. The correct account name is "Inventory Asset". Qty should be in negative to decrease the qty in QB.